# Images with API REST (Symfony + FosRestBundle)

Tags: image, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm new with API REST and I have one question/problem.

Currently I have an API REST (FosRestBundle) with Symfony (2.8.1) and all is OK, I have a json response with an array with some data...one of this field is a image (in my backend I used VichUploaderBundle).

How I can do to send the image in json? I need to serialize the image? base64? JMSSerializer?

This is the correct way? Serialize the image and later, in the other client deserialize?

Thanks!!

Roger

Answer (score 1):

the correct way is to just serve the link to the ressource

like:

```
[
{
 bla: "blubb",
 img: "http://blubb.com/blubb.jpg"
},
{
 bla: "blubb1",
 img: "http://blubb.com/blubb1.jpg"
},
{
 bla: "blubb2",
 img: "http://blubb.com/blubb2.jpg"
}
]
```

and whatever then uses this data will call the URI to display the image